# javascript returning NaN when it is compared with numbers to non-numbers

Tags: javascript

```
function largerNum(num1,num2){
  c = (num1>num2)?num1:num2;

return c;
}

console.log('largerNum(2095,106) returns: ' + largerNum(2095,106));
console.log('largerNum("23",14) returns: ' + largerNum("23",14));
console.log('largerNum(108,"a") returns: ' + largerNum(108,"a"));

console.log("\n");
```

for this code, it compares two parameters and returns the bigger number and I wanted to see how I could return NaN, when it is compared with numbers to something that is not number like (108,a)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: surely some web research should have given you some hints

Comment: Why not use Math.max? It returns the larger number and `NaN` if either operand is not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function largerNum(num1,num2){
   if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
      return NaN;
   }
   c = (num1>num2)?num1:num2;
   return c;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

should be similar to this:

```
function largerNum(num1,num2)
{
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) return NaN;

  return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.max`

```
Math.max(1, 2);  // 2
Math.max(1, '2') // 2
Math.max(1, 'a') // NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function largerNum(a, b) {
    if (Number.isNaN(a) || Number.isNaN(b)) return NaN;
    return Math.max(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function largerNum(num1, num2){
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) return NaN;
  return (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
}

console.log('largerNum(2095,106) returns: ' + largerNum(2095,106));
console.log('largerNum("23",14) returns: ' + largerNum("23",14));
console.log('largerNum(108,"a") returns: ' + largerNum(108,"a"));

console.log("\n");
```